# Showing that a sequence of random variables converges to $0$ in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence of identically distributed random variables $(X_n)$, with $E|X_n|$ finite. Define $Y_n = \operatorname{sup}(|X_1|, \dots, |X_n|)/n$. I must prove that $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in $L_1$.

If $\Omega$ is the domain of the random variables, then $n Y_n(\omega) \leq x$ if, and only if, $|X_i|(\omega) \leq x/n$ for $i=1, \dots, n$. Thus, $Y_n^{-1}((-\infty, x]) = \bigcap_{i=1}^nX_i^{-1}((-\infty, x/n])$. Then $P(Y_n\leq x) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^nX_i^{-1}((-\infty, x/n]))$. Does it follow from this that $Y_n$ is identically distributed to some of the $|X_i|$? Are there any hypothesis that may be missing?

Edit: there was a typo in the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. From the inequality
$$\sup\Bigl\{\lvert X_1\rvert,\ldots,\lvert X_n\rvert\Bigr\}\,\mathbf1_{\{\exists 1\le i\le n:\lvert X_i\rvert>n\varepsilon\}}\le\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert X_i\rvert\,\mathbf1_{\{\lvert X_i\rvert>n\varepsilon\}}$$
and the fact that the $X_i$'s are identically distributed, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[Y_n]&=\mathbb E\!\left[Y_n\,\mathbf 1_{\{\forall 1\le i\le n:\lvert X_i\rvert\le n\varepsilon\}}\right]+\mathbb E\!\left[Y_n\,\mathbf 1_{\{\exists 1\le i\le n:\lvert X_i\rvert>n\varepsilon\}}\right]\\[.4em]
&\le\varepsilon+\mathbf E\!\left[\lvert X_1\rvert\,\mathbf 1_{\{\lvert X_1\rvert>n\varepsilon\}}\right]\!.
\end{align*}
Thus, because $\mathbf E[\lvert X_1\rvert]<\infty$,
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E[Y_n]\le\varepsilon.$$
This is true for all $\varepsilon>0$, so we can conclude that $Y_n\to0$ in $\mathrm L^1$.